# Prove that $\dim \mathcal P(\Bbb F)/U = \deg p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

From *Linear Algebra Done Right*, Third Edition, Ch4 Ex11 by Sheldon Axler:

> Suppose $p\in\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$ with $p\ne 0$.  Let $U=\{pq : q\in\mathcal P(\Bbb F)\}$.
>
> (a) Show that $\dim \mathcal P(\Bbb F)/U = \deg p$.
> (b) Find a basis of $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)/U$.

I can clearly see that the dimension of $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)/U$ must be at least the degree of $p$ because any polynomial with degree less than $p$ will not be in $U$ and there are $\deg p$ of those.  But then not every polynomial of degree at least $\deg p$ will have $p$ as a factor.  So intuitively I'd think it was infinite, but that's obviously wrong.

Another idea I had was to figure out the dimension of $\mathcal P_m(\Bbb F)/U$ and then take a limit as $m\to \infty$.  But I can't figure out what the dimension of $U$ is.

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to get started on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q$ is a polynomial with bigger degree than $p$, I can divide $q$ by $p$ and get $q = \lambda p + r$, with $\lambda$ a polynomial and $r$ of polynomial of degree $ 0 \leq \deg(r) < \deg(p)$. So $q = r$ in $P(\mathbb F)/U$. This gives us that $P(\mathbb F)/U \cong \mathbb F\{1,x,x^2, \dots x^n\}$.

Comment: +1, maybe you would please explain what happened to the $p\in U$, i.e., $U=pq$? It looks like you are taking $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$ $\pmod q$. Thanks. And cool avatar!

Comment: @TheBirdistheWord When he wrote $q=r$, he did mean equality in the sense of $\bmod q$.  In our book, the notation would be $q+U = r+U$.

Comment: @TheBirdistheWord : Thanks ! I wanted to reply but the explanations of Bobbie D are correct. The point is that any $q$ with degree greater than $p$ can be written $q = u + r$ with $u \in U$ and $r \in \mathbb F\{1,x, \dots, x^n\}$, so you have an isomorphism $P(\mathbb F)/U \cong \mathbb F{1,x, \dots, x^n}$.